# Binding reducers to subset of the state, dynamically set

Tags: javascript, redux, state, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am currently starting with Redux and it is unclear to me what is the proper way of binding reducer to sub, dynamically set, parts of the state.

For instance let's say my state looks like this (after asynchronously fetching some data from backend APIs)

```
{
   "categories": {
      "collection": {
        "42": {
           "id": "42",
           "title": "whatever",
           "owner_id": "10"
           "posts": {
              "collection": {
                "36": {
                   "id": "36", 
                   "title": "hello",
                   "content": "hello world"
                },
                "37": { // more posts ... } 
              },
              "ids": ["36", "37", ...]
           },
           "otherChildren": { // more sub-entities } 
        },
        "43": { // more categories ... }
      },
      "ids": ["42", "43", ...]
   },
   "users": {
     "collection": {
       "10": {
          "id": "10"
          "email": "what@ever.com"
       },
       "11": { // more users ... } 
     },
     "ids": [10, 11]
   }
}
```

My root reducer would look like this :

```
export default combineReducers({
    categories: categoriesReducer,  
    users: usersReducer
})
```

and the categoriesReducer :

```
function categoriesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        categories: { 
          collection: action.payload 
        } 
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now what I'd like to do is to seamlessly delegate handle the `post` subset part of the state with postsReducer function, basically adding a case like :

```
  case FETCH_CATEGORY_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS:
    let categoryId = action.categoryId 
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      categories: {
        [categoryId]: combineReducers({
           "posts": postsReducer,
           "otherChildren": otherChildrenReducer
        })
      }
    }
```

Of course, this isn't working. What I don't get is how to get redux to automatically update a subset of the state using combineReducer for nested reducers, while automatically passing the proper subset as state argument to the reducer function, and without overriding the existing data (i.e. the category in my example).

I somehow managed to make that work writing my own "delegate" fonction, but it feels pretty wrong - especially looking at https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js which looks like doing exactly that.

How am I, conventionally, suppose to do that? Is that even possible to use combineReducers that way with Redux, am I misunderstanding the point of combineReducer or am I expecting to much magic from it ?

Thanks !

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I do really need those to be nested (right, maybe the `category`/`post` example isn't the right one) and I'd like the reducer (i.e. here, postsReducer, but it could be a `Collection` reducer) to re-usable in multiple places.

(*Why do I want it to be nested ?* Actually in that example, let's say that one `post` can only belong to one `category`, since data of `post` are actually encrypted with a private key from `category`. That why it makes so much sens to me to represent this chain, this relation in the state)

Isn't there a way with redux to delegate to other reducer while passing the proper subset of the state - that is, for instance, passing state `categories.collection.42.posts.collection.36` to a postReducer ?

Comment: For what it's worth, nothing gets "automatically" updated.  Reducers are **just functions**.  You may want to read through http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html to get some ideas.

Comment: If you want to have similar or exactly similar reducers for different data entities, then look at writing a reducer generator: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers, also here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html. You can do delegation, but only in a single direction (from less specific to more specific). The end result is a reducer tree. But what you're talking about sounds like circular delegation.

Comment: If you really want to nest one type of data entity within another in the store, of course you're free to do that, as long as you implement the reducers in a tree form. As markerikson above suggested, I also suggest you go back and read the docs on http://redux.js.org, they're very well-written and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You where doing it so nice with the store, why not keep on separating all the diferent collections.

I mean your posts should/could have another reducer, the store would en up like this:

```
{
   categories: [],
   posts: [],
   users: []
}
```

Your categories would then contain only the ID's of the posts

So you could "capture" the "FETCH_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS" action in both reducers (categories and the new posts reducer), on categoryReducer you safe the category data, and the ID's, and the postsReducer will just save the posts

Comment: thanks @Borjante. I update the question with a few more details, see above!

Answer (score 0):

You are using combineReducers in the wrong way in the last code snippet. (It is correct in the first snippet where you're using it to combine categoriesReducer and usersReducer together.)

In the case of FETCH_CATEGORY_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS, instead of calling combineReducers, just call a plain function inside of categoriesReducer.

```
posts: posts(action.payload.posts)
```

That plain function is basically a sub-reducer. It would be sth you write yourself, and you'd probably put it in the same file.

But two other main issues with your code above:

1) As another user has already said above, it probably wouldn't be best to store posts as a sub-property of categories. Rather store the posts as their own item within the state tree, and just have a `category_id` field for each post to show which category it belongs to. So your state tree in that case would look like:

```
{
  categories: {},
  posts: {},
  users: {}
}
```

and you would use combineReducers initially as:

```
export default combineReducers({
  categories: categoriesReducer,  
  posts: postsReducer,
  users: usersReducer
})
```

2) Within the categoriesReducer (or any for that matter), you don't have to have the `categories` property, because you've already created that property when calling `combineReducers`. In other words in `categoriesReducer` you ought to just have it as this:

```
function categoriesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        collection: action.payload,
        ids: // function to extract ids goes here
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @NateQ. I update the question with a few more details, see above !